# In Memoriam: Gary Graham

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Gary Graham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_Graham) has died at the age of 73 on Monday 22 January 2024 of a cardiac arrest.

Know for his roles as [Soval](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Soval) in *Star Trek: Enterprise* and [Detective Matthew "Matt" Sikes](https://hero.fandom.com/wiki/Matthew_Sikes) in the *Alien Nation* TV series and several subsequent TV movies.

Comment: I remember Alien Nation, but I never put it together than he was also Soval on *Enterprise*. RIP.